# Prepopulate dynamically made form php

Tags: php, sql, for-loop, while-loop

I got the following problem: I made a form that based on the amount of products in the database that meet certain requirements have a certain amount of inputs. This is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($submissionid) && isset($producttitle)) {
  $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM submissies WHERE submissie_id = '$submissionid' ";
  $data = $conn ->query($sql3);
  $result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);


  $nrofproducts = $result2[$producttitle];
  settype($nrofproducts, "integer");

}
$psql = "SELECT * FROM product_status WHERE task_id = '$submissionid' AND product_title = '$producttitle'";
$pdata = $conn ->query($psql);
$presult = (isset($pdata))? mysqli_fetch_assoc($pdata) : '';

//GEBRUIK HASH VOOR PID< OM ZE TOCH IETS UNIEK TE GEVEN
if (!empty($presult)) {
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for ($b = 0; $b < $nrofproducts; $b++ ) {
      $sql6 = "DELETE FROM product_status WHERE task_id = '$submissionid' AND product_title = '$producttitle'";
      mysqli_query($conn, $sql6);
    }
    for ( $b = 0; $b < $nrofproducts; $b++ ) {
      $serialnr = $_POST['serialnr'. $b];
      $pstatus = $_POST['pstatus' . $b];
      $additional_info = $_POST['bijzonderheden' . $b];
      $merk = $_POST['merk' . $b];
      $type = $_POST['type' . $b];
      $datechecked = date("d-m-Y");
      $sql8 = "INSERT INTO product_status ( product_title, serie_nr, product_status, task_id, bijzonderheden, merk, type, datum_gekeurd) VALUES ('$producttitle', '$serialnr', '$pstatus', '$submissionid', '$additional_info', '$merk', '$type', '$datechecked')";
      mysqli_query( $conn, $sql8);
    }
    header('Location: task.php?id='.$submissionid);
  }
} else {
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for ( $a = 0; $a < $nrofproducts; $a++ ) {
      $serialnr = $_POST['serialnr'. $a];
      $pstatus = $_POST['pstatus' . $a];
      $additional_info = $_POST['bijzonderheden' . $a];
      $merk = $_POST['merk' . $a];
      $type = $_POST['type' . $a];
      $datechecked = date("d-m-Y");
      $sql4 = "INSERT INTO product_status ( product_title, serie_nr, product_status, task_id, bijzonderheden, merk, type, datum_gekeurd) VALUES ('$producttitle', '$serialnr', '$pstatus', '$submissionid', '$additional_info', '$merk', '$type', '$datechecked')";
      mysqli_query( $conn, $sql4);

      header('Location: task.php?id='.$submissionid);
    }
  }
}
?>

<html elements etc>

<?php 
for ($i=0; $i < $nrofproducts; $i++):
    if ($producttitle == "blusslang" || $producttitle == "vluchtset" || 
        $producttitle == "ademluchtslang" || $producttitle == "ademluchtkap" || 
        $producttitle == "h2s_meter" || $producttitle == "bhv_verbandtrommer" || 
        $producttitle == "aed") 
    {
          $showbrand = "no";
    } else {
          $showbrand = "yes";
    }
?>
    <form action="product.php?product=<?=$producttitle;?>&submissionid=<?=$submissionid ;?>" method="post">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?=$i + 1; ?></th>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="<?=($showbrand == "yes")? "text": "hidden";?>" class="form-control" name="merk<?= $i;?>" placeholder="Merk"></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="<?=($producttitle == "aed" || $producttitle == "bhv_verbandtrommel")? "hidden" : "text";?>" class="form-control" name="serialnr<?= $i;?>" placeholder="Serienummer" value="<?=($producttitle == "aed" || $producttitle == "bhv_verbandtrommel")? "1" : "" ;?>"></td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
                <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" name="pstatus<?php echo $i;?>">
                    <option value="gekeurd">Gekeurd</option>
                    <?=($producttitle == "gasmasker" || 
                        $producttitle == "vluchtset" || 
                        $producttitle == "ademluchtslang" || 
                        $producttitle == "ademluchtkap")?"" 
                        : '<option value="gerepareerd">Gerepareerd</option>';
                    ?>
                    <option value="afgekeurd">Afgekeurd</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bijzonderheden<?= $i;?>" placeholder="bijzonderheden">
            </td>
          </tr>
<?php 
    endfor; 
?>
        </tbody>
        </table>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Opslaan">
<!-- KNOP MET CHECKBOX, VOOR NIEUWLEVERING. HIERONDER DAN 1 VELD DIE ZE KUNNEN INVULLEN MET NIEUW PRODUCT EN DAN KUNNEN SUBMITTEN< DAT GAAT DAN NAAR DE FACTUREREN DATABASE. -->
<button class="btn btn-info"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: white;" href="task.php?id=<?=$submissionid; ?>">Ga terug</a></button>
    </form>
```

The result is this:
[Form dynamically created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et6c5.png)

As you can see this one has 10 rows, but depending on the product the number of rows vary, also the headers vary.

What I want is to fill in data from my database, in case the form was already filled in once (I already know how to check if the form is filled in). Then I want the user to be able to fill in/ edit all the forms and resubmit it. The problem I have is that I can't simply add a while loop that will fill in the field in, that will interfere with the for loop. What can I do?

example of while loop I would use to fill it in with data from the database:

```
$data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 'something");

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)): ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?=$row['name'];?></th>
      <td><input value="<?=$row['age'];?>"></td>
      <td><input value="<?=$row['whatver'];?>"></td>
      <td><input value="<?=$row['something'];?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I tried this code:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn->query("SELECT * FROM product_status WHERE task_id = '$submissionid' AND product_title = '$producttitle'"))): ?>
        <?php for ($i=0; $i < $nrofproducts; $i++):
          if ($producttitle == "blusslang" || $producttitle == "vluchtset" || $producttitle == "ademluchtslang" || $producttitle == "ademluchtkap" || $producttitle == "h2s_meter" || $producttitle == "bhv_verbandtrommer" || $producttitle == "aed") {
            $showbrand = "no";
          } else {
            $showbrand = "yes";
          }
          ?>
          <form action="product.php?product=<?=$producttitle;?>&submissionid=<?=$submissionid ;?>" method="post">
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"><?=$i + 1; ?></th>
              <td style="text-align:center"><input type="<?=($showbrand == "yes")? "text": "hidden";?>" class="form-control" name="merk<?= $i;?>" placeholder="Merk" value="<?=$row['product_title'];?>"></td>
              <td style="text-align:center"><input type="<?=($producttitle == "aed" || $producttitle == "bhv_verbandtrommel")? "hidden" : "text";?>" class="form-control" name="serialnr<?= $i;?>" placeholder="Serienummer" value="<?=($producttitle == "aed" || $producttitle == "bhv_verbandtrommel")? "1" : "" ;?>"></td>
              <td style="text-align:center">
                <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" name="pstatus<?php echo $i;?>">
                    <option value="gekeurd">Gekeurd</option>
                    <?=($producttitle == "gasmasker" || $producttitle == "vluchtset" || $producttitle == "ademluchtslang" || $producttitle == "ademluchtkap")?"" : '<option value="gerepareerd">Gerepareerd</option>' ;?>
                    <option value="afgekeurd">Afgekeurd</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bijzonderheden<?= $i;?>" placeholder="bijzonderheden">
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The good thing is that it shows the title of the product, the bad thing is that it is a never-ending loop. [Image of ouput (infinite rows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4NhA.png)

Another problem with the code i tried is that when the products aren't in the database yet it won't show any table rows, but it should, so the user can fill it in for the first time. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qUjR.png)

Comment: do you want to insert in database ? not clear

Comment: I want info that already is in the databse displayed, and then submit all the data again.

Comment: Edited my post, more clear now?

Comment: Beter! you can turn insert query in your while loop and insert datas fetched from select query : <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)):  $sql ="insert into your_table datas from your while loop";?>

Comment: Thank you for your response! So I am wondering, should I place the while loop right under the for loop then?

Comment: Hope it help you, and 2 ways to do that 1.youcan pass row to an array then excract to insert in database. 2. is you can use hidden inputs.

Comment: I sent my comment by accident, wasn't done yet xd:)

Comment: yes, right under while loop if you are going to pass data to array. good luck

Comment: I tried it, what happend was an infinte amount of rows, but the title was there!

Comment: I added my code, which is a never ending loop

Comment: See the answer example, I just updated answer you can use it.

Comment: !!! WARNING !!! - You're using string variable expansion for your SQL queries, which means you're vulnerable to what's known as SQL Injection.  Please look into Prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example how you can do it.
Do what ever you want with loop, load data in to your inputs. and it will.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
   $row['name'];
   $row['age'];
   $row['whatver']
 }
```

After you are done with select query, then start doing insert query

```
 if(isset(submit)){
    // Do your filters here
    $sql = "INSERT INTO your_table(name, age, whatver) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $row['name'], $row['whatver'], $row['age']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 }
```

Dont forget to filter inputs.
Or you can do it with update query

```
 if(isset(submit)){
    // Do your filters here
    $sql = "UPDATE your_table SET name=?, age=?, whatver=?  WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isss", $_SESSION['id'], $row['name'], $row['whatver'], $row['age']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the while loop part:) Please checkout the edit section in my post. I added the code I tried, which kinda works (it shows the title of the product, from the database, as I wanted!), but throws an infinte amount of rows.

Comment: I can see images due to  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED dont know why :)

Comment: Oh weird! It basically shows an infinite amount of rows, but with the data in it, what I want!

Comment: In short, the problem is, how do I make sure the while and for loop don't interfere with each other.

Comment: Actually my example is for auto inserting in to database, but yours is on submition, so you got to do it out of the while loop, other wise you will get infinite query. use same query out of the while loop in your if(isset(submit)) its like select and update, see this link scroll down to update.php it is almost same as what you want  :  https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php

Comment: Oh sorry, now I see that! my bad! I will try it.

Comment: But I don't want to load in the data after submit is clicked, I want to load the data instantly into the fields that are created.

Comment: I am going to use the link you provide and find another way, that hopefully works:) I was so close!

Comment: I tried out the info from the link you provide, thanks btw! I can use that for some other stuff! But for this it is not exactly what I want. The idea is that a user can fill in the form partly, submit it to the database and then continue where he comes back again.

Comment: I realy dont get sorry! do you want to load data on page first and then insert in to database with clicking submit button right ? or you want to load and submit data instantly without clicking submit button ?

Comment: I want to load the data into the value attribute of the input fields, and then submit it if the user clicks on the submit button (like this: value="<?=$row['product_title'];?>") (See my tried code)

Comment: thanks for clearing ! So My answer and example in the link boths are your answers, user doesnt need to fill in the form as select will fill the form instantly and just need to click submit button to reinsert into database, Answer and example in link both doing same thing. (insert or update)

Comment: Yes, maybe you are thinking why would you submit the same data, which came from the database back to the database, but I use this when not all data is filled in, in the first place, and it is  a way to edit the data

Comment: Yes, but also refill other fields

Comment: And, they can fill in the form half way, submit it (it will only submit the status then, so all the fields will be empty, but the status won't be) and continue with filling it in.

Comment: Ok! glad I didnt west your time with misunderstanding your question and giving wrong answer ):